# It.IsAny<T> for unit testing for type:- params Action<IResultsReader>[]

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing unit test and i have this function:-

```
void QueryMultipleFromStoredProcedure(string sproc, object parameters, params Action<IResultsReader>[] readerFuncs);
```

I am not sure what is the type for params Action< IResultsReader >[]. I wrote this in my unit test:-

```
mockDataInfrastructure.Setup(x => x.QueryMultipleFromStoredProcedure(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<T>));
```

what would be the last one return type?

Comment: `It.IsAny<Action<IResultsReader>[]>`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, it says cannot convert from method group to action<IresultReader>

Comment: You've missed `()` -> `It.IsAny<Action<IResultsReader>[]>()`

Comment: Ohh right. It worked with this:-   It.IsAny<Action<IResultsReader>>(). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reuse the same interface as in the signature of your method :

```
mock.Setup(x => x.QueryMultipleFromStoredProcedure(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Action<IResultsReader>[]>()));
```

Comment: I am getting this error :- cannot convert type IresultReader to System.Action<IresultReader>

Comment: Sorry I just fixed my answer. It should compile now.